# Pine script is converting the result of a simple calculation from an int to a series[float]

Tags: pine-script

The result the calculation "int(DefEMAHiN1Min / BarMins + 0.5)" seems to be a series[float] regardless of what I try.  I just need it to be a simple int.  The result cannot be used in my input() call.

```
//@version=4

// The objective here is to show an EMA that adjusts to the bar size, 
// so the price crossings happen at the same times 
// even if the bar size is changed.
study("AdjustingEMA", overlay=true)

int DefEMAHiN1Min = 5500  // Use value for 1 min bars here

// BarMins calc is from https://www.tradingview.com/script/5k3yj1L8-JS-DMI-Bars/
int BarMins =
     timeframe.isdaily   ? timeframe.multiplier * 86400000 :
     timeframe.isseconds ? timeframe.multiplier * 1000     :
     timeframe.isminutes ? timeframe.multiplier * 60000    :
     (time[0]-time[1])

// This works fine here:  int DefEMAHiN = 92
int DefEMAHiN = int(DefEMAHiN1Min / BarMins + 0.5) // Seems to be a type conversion here.

// The next line results in: Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 22:
//      Declared type integer is not compatible with assigned type series[float]
int EMAHiN = input(title="EMAHiN", defval=DefEMAHiN, type=input.integer)

EMAHi = ema(close, EMAHiN)

plot(EMAHi)
```

Comment: You cannot use `BarMins` as it is not constant value, This value is unknown at compile time (Series type), and input() function can accept only constants.

Comment: That is not a solution to my problem.  I need to have a way to calculate BarMins automatically so I can adjust my EMA, including the offset, automatically when I change the bar size using the dropdown in the upper left.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the [] operator.  It is applied to a series (e.g., time[0] in the original example) and it returns a SERIES, not a scalar.  This fact is buried deep in the ([reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%5B%5D)).  This is different than any other language I have ever used, and is, in my option, very stupid.  I don't even see a built-in function that would do that.

The following tested solution does exactly what I wanted.

```
//@version=4

// The objective here is to show an EMA that adjusts to the bar size,
// so the price crossings happen at the same times
// even if the bar size is changed.
// The solution must also address the EMA offset.
study("AdjustingEMA", overlay=true)

float EMAHiN    = 5500  // Use the value validated for 1 min bars here
float EMAHiOff  =  550  // Use the value validated for 1 min bars here

float BarMins =
     timeframe.ismonthly ? timeframe.multiplier * 43200 :
     timeframe.isweekly  ? timeframe.multiplier * 10080 :
     timeframe.isdaily   ? timeframe.multiplier * 1440  :
     timeframe.isminutes ? timeframe.multiplier         :
     timeframe.isseconds ? timeframe.multiplier / 60.0  :
     0
// timeframe.isseconds case is untested

EMAHiN   := EMAHiN   / BarMins + 0.9999 // 0.9999 needed due to truncation on conversion
EMAHiOff := EMAHiOff / BarMins + 0.9999 // 0.9999 needed due to truncation on conversion

EMAHi = ema(close, int(EMAHiN))

plot(EMAHi, color = color.red, offset = int(EMAHiOff))
```